# XFS only using first allocation group despite inode64 mount option

Tags: xfs

Background: we've been seeing incredibly slow performance allocating files, on a system that creates many small files on a 25T disk. We found from http://xfs.9218.n7.nabble.com/1B-files-slow-file-creation-only-AG0-used-td1606.html that indeed it seemed like all files were getting created in the first AG.

```
for x in {0..38}; do echo -n "${x}: "; xfs_db -c "agi ${x}" -c "print" -r /dev/md1 | grep "^count"; done
0: count = 194711488
1: count = 0
2: count = 0
3: count = 0
4: count = 0
5: count = 0
6: count = 0
7: count = 0
8: count = 0
9: count = 0
10: count = 0
11: count = 0
12: count = 0
13: count = 0
14: count = 0
15: count = 0
16: count = 0
17: count = 0
18: count = 0
19: count = 0
20: count = 0
21: count = 0
22: count = 0
23: count = 0
24: count = 0
25: count = 0
26: count = 0
27: count = 0
28: count = 0
29: count = 0
30: count = 0
31: count = 0
32: count = 0
33: count = 0
34: count = 0
35: count = 0
36: count = 0
37: count = 0
38: count = 0
```

So, we remounted with the inode64 option, expecting that it would start using the other AGs and improve performance.

Performance did seem to improve a bit but was still unreliable, it seemed to vary. And further, rerunning the above command, I still see count = 0 for all AGs except the first one.

In further weirdness, it looks like AGs beyond the first only have 5 blocks.

```
# xfs_db -c "freesp -a 0" -c "print" -r /dev/md1
   from      to extents  blocks    pct
      1       1   58586   58586   0.02
      2       3   40188   95811   0.04
      4       7  119478  504965   0.20
      8      15   51112  490250   0.19
     16      31   22071  456215   0.18
     32      63   14025  634223   0.25
     64     127  474758 54537529  21.43
    128     255   28449 6001372   2.36
    256     511   13115 5007894   1.97
    512    1023    4764 3441878   1.35
   1024    2047    1952 2783230   1.09
   2048    4095     883 2536350   1.00
   4096    8191     477 2742390   1.08
   8192   16383     208 2330731   0.92
  16384   32767     121 2719892   1.07
  32768   65535      37 1518146   0.60
  65536  131071      24 2023965   0.80
 131072  262143       9 1595257   0.63
 262144  524287       1  349393   0.14
1048576 2097151       1 1345705   0.53
134217728 268435328       1 163286552  64.17
no current type

# xfs_db -c "freesp -a 1" -c "print" -r /dev/md1
   from      to extents  blocks    pct
      1       1       5       5 100.00
no current type
```

Having almost no blocks would explain why nothing is getting allocated there, but why would these have so few blocks? Or am I misreading this data? (I'm not an XFS expert)

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Was this filesystem originally created at 25TB or was it _much_ smaller and later resized?

Comment: I don't believe it was ever resized.